# How to display data from another controller in pages? CakePHP 4.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I want to connect articles to pages but i get error last screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Your template file is named `home`, but the controller action is called `homepage`?

Comment: Don't post code as screenshouts

Answer (score 0):

In your home page action

```php
public function homepage() {
    $this->loadModel('Articles');
    $lastArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', ['limit' => 3, 'order' => 'Articles.created DESC'])->toArray();

$this->set('lastArticles', $lastArticles);

}
```

`View::set` expects 2 parameters, one being the name of the variable in the view and the 2nd being the values of that variable for the view.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the PageController.php, I never used that controller for something else than the display() method. I don't know if what you're doing is the intended use.

If you want to list your articles I'd suggest you set that up in the ArticlesController.php.

```
//in src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
public function home() {
$lastArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', ['limit' => 3, 'order' => 'Articles.created DESC']);
  $this->set('lastArticles', $lastArticles);
}
```

Then you need to create a view template named corresponding to the method name in the controller [(see Naming Conventions)](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/intro/conventions.html) - for the method I posted it's "home.php".

```
//in templates/Articles/home.php
<?php foreach ($lastArticles as $lastArticle): ?>
//.. your fields ..
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```